# EF6 database architecture for shared entities: products2images, categories2images

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I have three primary entities on working production application: Product, Category and HtmlPage

```cs
public class Product {
    [Key]
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    //and other properties
}
public class Category {
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    //and other properties
}
public class HtmlPage {
    [Key]
    public string Id {get;set;}
    //and other properties
}
```

and one shared entity: Image

```cs
public class Image {
    public Guid Id {get;set;}
    //and other properties
}
```

all primary entities have junction with shared entity like this

```cs
public class ProductImage{
    public Guid ImageId {get;set;}
    public Guid ProductId {get;set;}
    //list of junction properies: order, isprimary and so on
}
```

I don't like this approach because in case of a large number of primary entities types it will be difficult to manage code and everything.
And i see some kind of troubles in case of a large number of shared entities types (Comments,Tags, Votes and so on)

and the problem is that i realy have to add new primary entities and shared entities in exists architecture right now.

So, i am thinking about database architecture refactoring

`ideal solution` as i see is

```cs
public abstract class EntityProxy
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityImageEntityProxy> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityTagEntityProxy> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityCommentEntityProxy> Comments { get; set; }
}

// list of Shared Entities
public class EntityImage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityImageEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}
public class EntityTag
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityTagEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}
public class EntityComment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityCommentEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}

// shared entities to primary entities mapping
public class EntityImageEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual EntityImage Image { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}
public class EntityTagEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TagId")]
    public virtual EntityTag Tag { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}
public class EntityCommentEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CommentId")]
    public virtual EntityComment Comment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}

// list of primary entities
[Table("EntityProxyProducts")]
public class EntityProxyProduct : EntityProxy
{
    //type properties
}
[Table("EntityProxyCategories")]
public class EntityProxyCategory : EntityProxy
{
    //type properties
}
[Table("EntityProxyHtmlPages")]
public class EntityProxyHtmlPage : EntityProxy
{
    //type properties
}
```

This implies rewriting the entire application due to the change in types of primary entities keys and i have my doubts about the performance
images - 100 000 - 200 000 entries
products - 30 000 - 50 000 entries

the second solution i see is merge `ideal solution` with existing models like this:

```cs
    // lis of exists primary entities
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? EntityProxyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxyProduct EntityProxy { get; set; }
    //and other properties
}
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? EntityProxyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxyCategory EntityProxy { get; set; }
    //and other properties
}
public class HtmlPage
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Guid? EntityProxyId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxyHtmlPage EntityProxy { get; set; }
    //and other properties
}


public abstract class EntityProxy
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityImageEntityProxy> Images { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityTagEntityProxy> Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityCommentEntityProxy> Comments { get; set; }
}

// list of Shared Entities
public class EntityImage
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityImageEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}
public class EntityTag
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityTagEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}
public class EntityComment
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EntityCommentEntityProxy> Entities { get; set; }
}

// shared entities to primary entities mapping
public class EntityImageEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid ImageId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual EntityImage Image { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}
public class EntityTagEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid TagId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TagId")]
    public virtual EntityTag Tag { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}
public class EntityCommentEntityProxy
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid CommentId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid EntityProxyId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CommentId")]
    public virtual EntityComment Comment { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("EntityProxyId")]
    public virtual EntityProxy Entity { get; set; }
}

// list of primary entities proxies
[Table("EntityProxyProducts")]
public class EntityProxyProduct : EntityProxy
{
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
[Table("EntityProxyCategories")]
public class EntityProxyCategory : EntityProxy
{
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
[Table("EntityProxyHtmlPages")]
public class EntityProxyHtmlPage : EntityProxy
{
    public virtual ICollection<HtmlPage> HtmlPages { get; set; }
}
```

The negative in the second solution is the fact that it's impossible to create one-to-zero..one relation with non primary key properties and the only way i see is to create it like one-to-many and take care of db safe from the code - not good.

so, my question is what i have to do?
• take a beer and do it fashioned way without implementing any architectural refactoring
• must summon the courage to implement the `perfect solution` with rewriting everything
• take the lesser of two evils and implement mixed solution
• take a look at a more jedi solution

and what kind of performance difficulties I may face?

Any advice, links and docs are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you prefer to work with a document-centric view of your data, have you considered using a document database instead of relational sql for this?

Comment: No, sir. My current DB is mssql 2012 and i am not going to change it at this moment but maybe i should